# applying affine transform to one image based on another image

Tags: opencv, alignment, computer-vision, affinetransform

I have some doubts regarding Affine Transform in open cv. The tutorial on http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html deals with only one image. Can Affine transform be used to make transform an image with reference to another image?

Comment: An affine transform is applied to an image to give another image. If you have two images with similar content but from different views, you can use these to derive an affine transform that maps between them. Sometimes. Can you explain more exactly what your confusion is?

Comment: thanks!yes I do have 2 images with similar content. Here are the images http://imgur.com/lDRIx6y,2roKEkv#0 and http://imgur.com/lDRIx6y,2roKEkv#1 . As you can see there are marker points on the face. I want to know if using affine transform is a good method to align the marker points from the left profile image onto the marker points of the front face image and how can I achieve this using affine transform.

Comment: Well you can use [`getAffineTransform`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=getaffinetransform#getaffinetransform) to see how it goes, but it's really best for mapping 2D planes rather than 3D objects. Also look at [`findHomography`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#Mat%20findHomography%28InputArray%20srcPoints,%20InputArray%20dstPoints,%20int%20method,%20double%20ransacReprojThreshold,%20OutputArray%20mask%29) if you need to get more complex.

Comment: yes I am using only 2D images..no 3D!but can I use findHomography for face images?Correct me if I am wrong, but I think findHomography is more useful when we have building images

Comment: findHomography` is useful wher there is perspective distortion, so it's more useful for big 3D scenes and of course it's easy to demonstrate using buildings with nice straight lines and easy to match corners. I think you need to refine your question because it's very broad and not really programming related.